# VNC viewer shows only black screen, but sends events to droidVNC

Tags: vnc

I am using a VNC server on my Android device (droidVNC it is called.)  I have tried using multiple VNC viewers and each one has the same results:

- the viewer window is a black screen (sometimes a blue screen.)
- clicking on the viewer correctly sends the events to the phone (I can see the screen change, etc.) but it is just blind clicking and pretty unusable.

I think that since this is the same problem on multiple different viewers (TightVNC Viewr, RealVNC Viewer) that it is a problem with droidVNC server.

Do you think the problem is actually with the VNC Viewer?

Has anybody experienced something like this before, and are there any tips you can give to make the droidVNC server run faster/better?

Comment: The Nook running CM7 has this problem for a while with both VNC and screenshot programs like ShootMe.  IIRC, the solution was a boot paramter change to alter framebuffer size.  You could give ShootMe a try and, if you get black screenshots, you know it isn't VNC.  Unfortunately, if it is the framebuffer, you're out of luck.

Comment: Hey Earl, thanks a lot for the comment. ShootMe (which turns out to be called PicMe) works great. And actually, it seems to be its own VNC server, because clicking the "Live" option lets me send key events and move the mouse. Thanks again, if you want to post an answer I'll accept it. 

@Selvin thanks for the android.se link, and if you have suggestions for the tags I will update them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with droid VNC server. I have faced the same issue recently and the project seems to be abandoned (app last updated on June 11, 2012).

Then I tried different options under `Settings->Display Access Method`. The default option is `auto-detect`. I changed it to `Framebuffer`. Restarted the server and I could see the display on my viewer software. You should try all options till it works.

[image: screenshot]

Tested on my ancient phone GT-S5360 running Android 2.3.5 (Better options available for recent android versions but they don't work on 2.3.5. So, I needed to find a solution by any means)

Answer (score 0):

This was quite a bump, but I've also searched for ages for a good and reliable way to get the display and send events to android phones, and never had too much success. Pretty much every solution relied on an app on the phone, and they were quite laggy (like VNC usually is).

This all changed when I met [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy).

As the developer, puts it:

> scrcpy provides display and control of Android devices connected on USB (or over TCP/IP). It does not require any root access. It works on GNU/Linux, Windows and MacOS.

All that's required is ADB debugging enabled, and you're basically good to go. You can set the bitrate, the scaling, everything. But most importantly, *the latency is ridiculously low*.

If you're looking for a similar solution to this problem, I'd give it a go. I know I'll be never fiddling with remote desktop servers and clients anymore!